# Wu dialect children's learning materials

Tags: learning, games, shanghainese

Are there any good resources for teaching our child Wu dialect. I'm looking for games / music / toys that have spoken songs or dialog so he can listen. He is 19 months and we have been speaking English, Mandarin and Wu with him but I think Wu has the least resources to support his education.

Comment: I think the best learning material is you. And by the way, Wu dialect is quite different. It is really hard to find official learning material. I have one book to describe the dialect in my city. But it is only suitable in my city because no other Wu dialect cities using the word in this book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wu music in bilibili:

- [吴语乐坛](http://space.bilibili.com/39228238/#!/video)
- [吴语微信平台](http://space.bilibili.com/5083184/#!/video?keyword=&order=senddate&page=1&tid=3)

dialog:

- [真纪](http://space.bilibili.com/4835752/#!/index)

[Wu in forvo](https://zh.forvo.com/languages/wuu/)